# Technical difference between bent pipe and regenerative transponders

Tags: digital-communications

I am preparing a proposal for satellite transponders and need to choose transponder architecture.  Based on primary research I realized that the regenerative transponders have a better characteristic.
I am looking for a reference to extract the transponder characteristic(for example BER and SNR relationship).
Does anybody have any idea?
thanks a lot

Comment: um, not to sound mean, but: launching a satellite is expensive, and you can't replace things if it doesn't work. Are you sure you want to design this on your own transponder, instead of buying one? This is a **very** classic problem that communications engineers know; it's part of most textbooks: **decode and forward** versus **amplify and forward** are the keywords you should be searching for.

Comment: (other than that: designing a transponder takes way, way, way more specifications than you offer before you can get a BER curve...)

Comment: I am going to simulate the transponder for lecture projects and need some reference to extract important parameters. 
thank you

Comment: well, then, really, read up on decode-and-forward and amplify-and-forward. Also, a *link budget* will be what is expected of you to present.